# Sorting by div not working under Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, opera

I found this cool example of sorting data in a div table, but it's not working on Chrome and Opera.

jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg

Is there a better way to do this on every browser?

Comment: The code uses JQuery, are you including the JQuery import in your code ?